# Will it harm my video game if I take it through the scanner?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I want to take my video game home with my on the plane and don't want to put it in my checked luggage because they just carelessly toss luggage around. But I want to know if it is safe to take it through scanners; I've taken burned CD's through before and they were erased, I don't want that to happen to this $80 game. If anyone knows whether or not it is safe I would be very grateful!

Comment: Your CD's will **not** be harmed by any of the scanners used at airports! I'm not sure what actually happened to your CD's but this is just not true!

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can take your video games CDs safely through airport scanners. Airport scanners (either X-ray scanners or magnetic field scanners) won't damage CDs or DVDs by any means. Both CDs and DVDs are optical storage media and X-Rays do not interfere with them...